# How to get ReactJS Material-table search results count

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Material-table (https://material-table.com/#/) for my project.  I've been trying to figure out if there is a way to retrieve the search-result count when either filter or search actions are used.  I've looked through all the examples and properties but dont see any way to retrieve this information.

For example, if I have a total of 100 rows of data, and filter on "stackOverflow"...if the result list returns 50 rows of data that are now rendered, how do I get the "50" ?

Comment: Try getting the list of table children.

Comment: How do I access the filtered-table content from outside of the <MaterialTable> component ?

Comment: try this: this.dataSource.filteredData.length

Comment: i'm using a functional component so there is no "this" available.  The material table data is populated with <MaterialTable data={tabData} /> where tabData represents a state variable.  This variable does not get updated on a filter/search.  Where are you getting dataSource.filteredData.length from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tableRef` and [`onSearchChanged`](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) prop

This seems to work for well:

```
const tableRef = React.useRef();
...
<MaterialTable
      tableRef={tableRef}
      onSearchChange={() => {
        console.log(tableRef.current.DataManager.filteredData.length);
      }}.....
```

You can also find the filtered data in the few other paths:

1. `tableRef.current.DataManager.data`
2. `tableRef.current.state.data`